# How can I stop the Create New Method helper from showing in Visual Studio Community on the Mac OS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-mac

I don't think I am using a new version of VS but now this helper keeps on appearing and it's hard to get rid of so I can resume typing.

[image]I keep clicking esc and then after a few more clicks or if I decide to remove some spaces in the params it appears again. It's very annoying to keep seeing it. Has anyone else figured out a way to get rid of this for good?

Comment: This won't go away.  Five mins later and I am still trying to enter params and clicking on esc ever time I type anything.  Very annoying now.

Comment: I agree, most annoying "feature" ever.  Would love to hear how to turn it off (I toggling back and forth to an older version as this "feature" and the new "Visual Studio" style tab-completion which is the VS Windows' style but goes against the Apple/macOS UI and 5+ years of using Xamarin/VS4M is my biggest pain point, have not found a Setting that I switch it back either)

Comment: Agreed. This really ruins my day